# When using 'bash' or 'ksh', is there any alternative name for '\' when connecting lines?

Tags: terminology

Two lines can be linked together as a unit using '\' (which is a somewhat arbitrarily chosen character).  Accordingly both are parsed together.  What do you call the linking character.  I know that '#!' is the 'shebang' and ! is the bang, but what is the '\'?

Comment: `\ ` isn't very "arbitrary"; it's used as the escape character in many other places: `\"`, `\n`, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a [backslash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backslash).

Comment: In the context that the OP is asking about, the backslash is often referred to as a "line-continuation character".